# Recover from mistakenly restoring a different iPhone instead of back up

Tags: iphone, ios, backup

I was just trying to copy my photos with my PC, but I accidentally clicked to restore a back up of my husband iPhone. Everything shown on my mobile is from the back up and I don't see my data now. How do I access data from my iPhone?

Comment: Was your phone backup up?  To iCloud perhaps?

Comment: Essentially, you re-restore it from the correct backup.

Answer (score 1):

Not much you’re left with, it’s either restoring from [iCloud](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph12521?locale=en_US) backup or [iTunes backup](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204184#iTunes). iTunes may have backed up your phone during a sync. So you may have a backup from your phone, check it in iTunes -> Preferences -> Devices will list backups.